# How to fix "Error: This QuadStore is not registered"?

Tags: sqlite, cayley

I am trying to load a sample `chinook.db` database into Cayley. I am using a standart Cayley config file `cayley_example.yml` with small changes specific to `sqlite3`.

Here's [chinook.db](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/)

`cayley_example.yml`

```
store:
  # backend to use
  backend: sqlite
  # address or path for the database
  address: "./chinook.db"
  # open database in read-only mode
  read_only: false
  # backend-specific options
  options:
    nosync: false
query:
  timeout: 30s
load:
  ignore_duplicates: false
  ignore_missing: false
  batch: 10000
```

If I execute `./cayley init -c cayley_example.yml`, I get `Error: This QuadStore is not registered.` I tried to follow [this guide](http://oren.github.io/books/cayley/010_foundations/run.html) but `.cfg` files are not supported by the current Cayley version.

Answer (score 1):

While running the command `cayley init`, add flag `-d` and "storage type". For your case-
`cayley init -d "sql"`

Answer (score 1):

Check if Cayley version that you use supports SQLite:

```
cayley -h
```

You would see a list of supported backends in the help message for `-d` option:

```
  -d, --db string  database backend to use:
                   badger, bolt, btree, ..., mysql, postgres, sql (default "memstore")
```

If you built the binary from source, make sure you built the latest one and `CGO_ENABLED=1` is set.